# post_content on more than one field?

Tags: wordpress, function, post, syntax

Is it possible to have more than one name="post_content" on a form?

I have a Contact Form 7, where I need to assign post_content to more than one input field. Now it only takes and publish the content from the last field.

Thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If youre going to have more than 1 the same name field then you have to make it an array or else it wont work

```
name="post_content[]"
```

Comment: I know how I would do it with dropdowns, but I do not know how to do it with text inputs.